# Conditional list from a dictionary vs. Searching a dictionary with a condition - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'red':1,'green':2,'blue':3}
```

I am allowed to create a list of keys from this dictionary that match a condition using the following syntax:

```
mylist = [k for k in d if d[k] > 1]
print mylist

>>>> ['blue', 'green']
```

But if I try to search through a dictionary with a condition using a similar line of code, this does not work:

```
for k in d if d[k] > 1:
    print k, d[k]

>>>>for k in d if d[k] > 1:
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is not the case? Or if I am doing something wrong? It seems like if I am allowed to combine looking through the dictionary with a conditional statement when making a list, I should also be allowed to do this when looking through the dictionary without making a list.

I am working in Python 2.7.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
for k in d if d[k] > 1:
    print k, d[k]
```

You should simply be writing:

```
for k in d:
    if d[k] > 1:
        print k, d[k]
```

The list-comprehension syntax that puts it all on one `[k for k in d if d[k] > 1]` line is just syntactic sugar for the above.

**Edit:** Though as I mentioned in the comments below, you can do something tricky with generator comprehensions. A generator comprehension, in case anyone who reads this answer later doesn't know, is similar to a list comprehension, but it produces a *generator*, an iterable object that you can stick into a for loop (or stick in a variable for later processing). So you can do:

```
g = (k for k in d if d[k] > 1)
```

and later on,

```
for k in g:
    print k, d[k]
```

Or, combined into one operation (though this is a little bit ugly):

```
for k in (x for x in d if d[x] > 1):
    print k, d[k]
```

Note that the `x` inside the generator comprehension could have been `k` as well, but I chose to use a different name so it would be clearer what's going on. The name `x` is *not* in scope outside the comprehension, by the way:

```
for k in (x for x in d if d[x] > 1):
    print k, d[k], x
```

produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

As I said, that's a bit ugly since you end up having to write the `for` statement twice. (Once for the "what the generator does" code and once for the "I want to unroll the generator and get its results" code). But it's the closest you'll get to the "I want to do this in one line" syntax you're looking for.

Comment: I understand that I can write it out in two lines--like you suggested--but why is it that I can't write it out in one line like I can when creating a list?

Comment: @spacetyper - Simply because no syntactic sugar was ever created for the case you want, nor has any of the Python designers even wanted to create such syntactic sugar. It's only list comprehensions where the syntactic sugar was felt necessary.

Comment: @spacetyper - You can do something kind of tricky with generator comprehensions if you really want it on one line, but it's ugly and detracts from readability. For the sake of completeness, though, I'll add it to my answer (it wouldn't post well in a comment).

Comment: @spacetyper - Okay, answer edited to include how to do this with generator comprehensions. It's actually less ugly than I thought if you assign the comprehension to a separate variable. Which is a good idea, because then you can save off the result and do it later, but *no work gets done until you actually need the result*. It's lazy, unlike the list-comprehension method which is eager and thus does all the work up front.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @rmunn. If you however insist on one line, then this will work:

```
d = {'red':1,'green':2,'blue':3}
for k, v in ((k, v) for (k, v) in d.items() if v > 1):
    print k, v
```

It only does one dictionary lookup. If you go for the solution provided by @rmunn, then I would reduce the dictionary lookups to just one.

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if v > 1:
        print k, v
```

As pointed out by @rmunn in the comments it is even better to use the lazy [`iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) in Python 2, which returns an iterator:

```
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if v > 1:
        print k, v
```

Comment: `d.iteritems()` might be even better, since the OP is using Python 2.x. His example is a tiny dictionary, but if he has a large dictionary in his real code he'd be much better off with `iteritems()` since it won't create an entire key/value list in memory all at once. But +1 for suggesting `d.items()` in the first place.

Comment: @rmunn Yeah man! You are totally right! I haven't done Python 2 for a while. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case it is a list comprehension.
The second case is nothing.